# compare two csv files in mule

Tags: csv, scripting, mule, mule-studio

I have to compare two csv files using Mule.

I have to find details like new rows added, deleted or updated. I have searched but there is no such feature/component.

Can I use a bash script in mule?

I know I can use a Java component, but am soliciting better suggestions or ideas. Please suggest pointers to get me started.

Comment: Why would a Java component be last after calling a bash script? It seems much less convoluted to me. If you want to skip the compilation aspect of a Java component, then use a MEL component.

Comment: @DavidDossot is this possible using MEL component? Please let me know

Comment: Re-read my above comment...

Answer (score 1):

In Mule you can leverage a Java component, and there are a [number of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864654/comparing-two-csv-files-in-java) to this problem using Java.