# Bean shell post processor ,which compares two csv files and writes differences to third file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin, ruby-jmeter

I am new to jmeter, I want to compare the two csv files ( one which have standard output and other latest test run results file), if there is any difference then it should write the difference to another file.

I want to do this in bean shell postprocessor

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two csv files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864654/comparing-two-csv-files-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't make a lot of sense as there are too many varying values (i.e. request timestamp, response time, connect time, latency, etc.) so basically you won't be able to find 2 identical lines in 2 JMeter result files for the same test plan.

I would recommend using one of the next alternative approaches:

- [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool (available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/site/logo.png)) provides possibility to merge/compare 2 or more JMeter results files:

  [image: JMeter Merge Results]

You can install Merge Results tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I am capturing request_data and response_data in a file and comparing it with current_testresults, if there are any mismatches I want to see those and why it happen( I mean want to check the response data).Here I am not worried with timing or size.I am checking only response data matches or not