# Git diff: is it possible to show ONLY changed lines

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I'm trying to get only new version of lines which have changed and not all the other info which git diff shows.

For:

```
git diff HEAD --no-ext-diff --unified=0 --exit-code -a --no-prefix
```

It shows:

```
diff --git file1 file2
index d9db605..a884b50 100644
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -16 +16 @@ bla bla bla
-old text
+new text
```

what I want to see is only:

```
new text
```

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git diff to show only lines that has been modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810623/git-diff-to-show-only-lines-that-has-been-modified)

Comment: Nope, it is not a duplicate, @metacubed I saw the question and incorporated the answer, but it did not help completely. I was able to get rid of heading and trailing lines but not all the other information.

Comment: I added an answer based on your specific question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Only added lines does not make sense in all cases. If you replaced some block of text and you happend to include a single line which was there before, git has to match and guess. - Usually the output of `git diff` could be used as input for `patch` afterwards and is therefore meaningful. Only the added lines are not precisely defined as git has to guess in some cases.

If you nevertheless want it, you cannot trust a leading `+` sign alone. Maybe filtering all the green line is better:

```
git diff --color=always|perl -wlne 'print $1 if /^\e\[32m\+\e\[m\e\[32m(.*)\e\[m$/'
```

for only deleted lines filter for all the red lines:

```
git diff --color=always|perl -wlne 'print $1 if /^\e\[31m-(.*)\e\[m$/'
```

to inspect the color codes in the output you could use:

```
git diff --color=always|ruby -wne 'p $_'
```

Comment: Why is the leading "+ " not trustworthy?

Comment: The file header starts with `+++` and if you add a line with two plus signs you result in `+++`, too. You could solve this with more parsing logic but just taking the green lines looks easier.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right. There is no space after the "+" in the git diff output. My mistake.

Comment: Awesome! How do I show deleted versions of the file?

Comment: Use `git diff --color=always|perl -wlne 'print $1 if /^\e\[32m\+\e\[m\e\[32m(.*)\e\[m$/'|sed -r 's/\x1B\[m\x1B\[41m[[:blank:]]+//g'` to remove trailing spaces color code. If you're using mac OS, replace `sed` with `docker run --rm -i hairyhenderson/sed`.

Comment: Why is this not working for [this commit](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/104e65a2081) where the lines start with a `-` sign, but are nevertheless red if you run `git diff 104e65a2081^ 104e65a2081`?

Answer (score 20):

If you specifically want only the `new text` part, then use the following:

```
git diff HEAD --no-ext-diff --unified=0 --exit-code -a --no-prefix | egrep "^\+"
```

This is basically your code, piped into the `egrep` command with a regex. The regex will filter only lines starting with a plus sign.

If you want to use this as an alias in scripting context, make sure to escape the escape char. Inside your `~/.gitconfig` file, add:

```
[alias]
  diffaddedonly = !git diff HEAD --no-ext-diff --unified=0 --exit-code -a --no-prefix | egrep '^\\+'
```

Comment: git diff HEAD^^ --no-ext-diff --unified=0 --exit-code -a --no-prefix | egrep "^\-[^\-]"

Comment: what about stripping the + sign prefix at the beginning of each line? I'm creating some crazy rebase recipes..

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

`git diff -U0 <commit-hash> | grep "^\+\""`

This will give your output as "+new text"

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer using `grep`. It retains the original red/green colors for readability. I provided a few variations in syntax:

```sh
git diff --color | grep --color=never $'^\e\[3[12]m'
git diff --color | grep --color=never $'^\033\[3[12]m'
git diff --color | grep --color=never -P '^\e\[3[12]m'
git diff --color | grep --color=never -P '^\033\[3[12]m'
```

Explanation:

- `git diff --color` is needed to prevent git from disabling the color when it is piping.
- `grep --color=never` prevents grep from highlighting the matched string (which removes the original color from the original command)
- Match lines that start with red (`\e[31m`) or green (`\e[32m`) escape codes.
- The `$'...'` (ANSI-C quoting syntax) or `-P` (perl syntax) is to let `grep` to interpret `\e` or `\033` as an `ESC` character.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the process to be automatic, for a single file, you can use `diff` rather than `git diff`, doing :

```
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' <( git show HEAD:myfile.ext ) myfile.ext
```

- <( ) makes `diff` use the result of `git show HEAD:myfile.ext` as first input
- `--changed-group-format='%>'` tells diff to output added lines
- `--unchanged-group-format=''` tells diff to output nothing for removed lines

For getting the info for a commit (not for the current worktree modifications), you can even do

```
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' <( git show _SHA_~:myfile.ext ) <( git show _SHA_:myfile.ext )
```

where `_SHA_` is any reference to a commit (SHA, branch, tag, ...)

(For those who wonder why I needed this : I've got a "update.sql" file in which all SQL statements are put. So, on project update, I've got to find which lines have been added, to make Mysql execute them).

I found these diff options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15385080/2955802)

Comment: Doesn't work for newly added file

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the color stuff isn't so portable to windows (with the commands supported by unxutils).  However there is a solution to the +++ problem solved by using the color mode.

Additionally we probably don't want the leading character either.  So lets use sed to get rid of it once we've matches with it:

`git diff --no-ext-diff --unified=0 -a --no-prefix --output-indicator-new=% | sed -n "s/^%\(.*\)$/\1/p"`

if you want deleted lines:

`git diff --no-ext-diff --unified=0 -a --no-prefix --output-indicator-old=% | sed -n "s/^%\(.*\)$/\1/p"`

By substituting % for + you don't have to worry about the header lines that start with +++ (b/c git doesn't use that prefix there... however that could change, this is still a porcelain command)

The prefix character must be ASCII (so no getting fancy with unicode).  Given the vagaries of Windows/Linux/sed syntax.  I think, the only ASCII chars that won't require escaping somewhere are: %,_~

Depending on your needs you may want to drop `-a`  as binary files can make a mess of things.

`--exit-code` mentioned in another answer is a noop.  By running thru a pipe, we only get the second exit code (tested on both Windows and Linux)

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic approach: Restore the old version (take care not to overwrite your changes), and use good old diff.