# RegEx, only show colored lines (from git diff output)

Tags: python, regex, git

I have a string `x` that looks like this. The lines with a plus in front are color coded.

```
diff --git js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java
index 55597bf..9115830 100644
--- js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java
+++ js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java
@@ -38,0 +39,6 @@ public class JsLineNumberTestGenerated extends AbstractJsLineNumberTest {
+    @TestMetadata("chainedCall.kt")
+    public void testChainedCall() throws Exception {
+        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/chainedCall.kt");
+        doTest(fileName);
+    }
+
@@ -92,0 +99,6 @@ public class JsLineNumberTestGenerated extends AbstractJsLineNumberTest {
+    @TestMetadata("longLiteral.kt")
+    public void testLongLiteral() throws Exception {
+        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/longLiteral.kt");
+        doTest(fileName);
+    }
+
```

I want to extract the green lines, so that in the end I have two strings (an array of strings) like this:

```
    @TestMetadata("chainedCall.kt")
    public void testChainedCall() throws Exception {
        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/chainedCall.kt");
        doTest(fileName);
    }
```

and

```
    @TestMetadata("longLiteral.kt")
    public void testLongLiteral() throws Exception {
        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/longLiteral.kt");
        doTest(fileName);
    }
```

The raw output of git diff is this (where you can also see the color code):

```
'\x1b[1mdiff --git js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java\x1b[m\n\x1b[1mindex 55597bf..9115830 100644\x1b[m\n\x1b[1m--- js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java\x1b[m\n\x1b[1m+++ js/js.tests/test/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/test/JsLineNumberTestGenerated.java\x1b[m\n\x1b[36m@@ -38,0 +39,6 @@\x1b[m \x1b[mpublic class JsLineNumberTestGenerated extends AbstractJsLineNumberTest {\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    @TestMetadata("chainedCall.kt")\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    public void testChainedCall() throws Exception {\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/chainedCall.kt");\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m        doTest(fileName);\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    }\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\n\x1b[36m@@ -92,0 +99,6 @@\x1b[m \x1b[mpublic class JsLineNumberTestGenerated extends AbstractJsLineNumberTest {\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    @TestMetadata("longLiteral.kt")\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    public void testLongLiteral() throws Exception {\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m        String fileName = KotlinTestUtils.navigationMetadata("js/js.translator/testData/lineNumbers/longLiteral.kt");\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m        doTest(fileName);\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m\x1b[32m    }\x1b[m\n\x1b[32m+\x1b[m'
```

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497881/git-diff-is-it-possible-to-show-only-changed-lines) I found a regex which actually can match for the green color, but I have problems with applying it to my concrete problem:

`/^\e\[32m\+\e\[m\e\[32m(.*)\e\[m$/`

Comment: Did you consider to grep for the lines starting with a `+` instead?  The point is that colors are discouraged when processing ASCII output of unix commands; they only make sense on a screen.  So many programs stop producing the color codes as soon as they notice that their output is passed into another command.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question goes for the color code, because there could be other lines with a plus in front. In addition I'm working in Python with GitPython, so there is no grep available.

Comment: I didn't mean the Unix command `grep`, I was referring to the act of grepping (*g*etting something which matches a *re*gular ex*p*ression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just test if the sequence is in the line:

```
for line in x.split('\n'):
    if '\x1b[32m' in line:
        print line
```

If you really need to find groups of lines which all contain a green-esc-sequence, you can do it like this:

```
import re

for chunk in re.findall(r'((?:[^\n]*\x1b\[32m[^\n]*\n)+)', x):
    print chunk
```

But I think searching for the escape-sequence is a hack.  `git` determines on the base of the terminal in use how to make something green etc.  If you go to a different terminal you might end up with different escape sequences.  Also, `git` might decide not to print color codes in case it notices its output isn't going to a terminal but to another process or a file.

I found no simple alternative, though, no tweaking `git` to print out added lines in a special format or similar.  So the only truly clean way of doing it would be to parse the `git` output completely (like `patch` would do), i. e. take the line numbers it says into account and ignore the formatting.  But that's not possible with a mere pattern matching.

Comment: Let me note that one can force git to output color codes with parameter ``--color=always``.

Comment: But it is not documented which color codes `git` will use.  It might be depending on the current terminal.  Version 2.7.4 on Linux, however, seems to be agnostic and use always the same color codes, regardless of the terminal.  I wouldn't bet that a later version or a Windows version (or something even more bizarr) would always do this.  Color codes are simply something not meant to be searched for.  Doing it nevertheless is a hack.