# how to view only modified text using git diff between two branches

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have a text file in main branch and also in my feature branch. I am editing the text file in feature branch and now want to see the difference between main branch and feature branch.

I am using the following command to see the difference

```
git diff main..feature input.txt

diff --git a/input.txt b/input.txt
index 3604999..98e6387 100644
--- a/input.txt
+++ b/input.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 # Lord of the rings

+bilbo baggins
+
```

Now i want to see only **bilbo baggins** but the code i am running shows the whole difference. How can i show only the newly added lines in the console?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497881/git-diff-is-it-possible-to-show-only-changed-lines) helping you?

Comment: Nope it is for files not for multiple branches

Comment: are you looking for `git diff -U0 main..feature input.txt` ?

Comment: Note that the two-dot sequence (`git diff main..feature`) is semi-deprecated at this point; use the two name sequence (`git diff main feature`) to make sure your code works in Git 3000 or whatever version it might eventually be, released in perhaps 2035 or something. :-) These two do exactly the same thing but most people find `git diff main feature` clearer, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```bash
git diff --color=always master..feature input.txt | perl -wlne 'print $1 if /^\e\[32m\+\e\[m\e\[32m(.*)\e\[m$/'
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25498422/13763683) and then adapted it for branches.

Comment: Did you commit it? If you specify `master..feature` it will do the difference between `master` branch and `feature` branch with commits. If you specify only `master` it will do the difference between `master` branch and your current working directory, so without commits.