# Diff to get changed line from second file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, diff

I have two files file1 and file2. I want to print the new line added to file2 using diff.
**file1**

```
/root/a
/root/b
/root/c
/root/d
```

**file2**

```
/root/new
/root/new_new
/root/a
/root/b
/root/c
/root/d
```

**Expected output**

```
/root/new
/root/new_new
```

I looked into man page but there was no any info on this

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384818/how-to-get-the-difference-only-additions-between-two-files-in-linux .

Comment: @Jordan Samuels As someone already commented in that other question, it will leave you with a + at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to preserve the order, you could use the `comm` command like:

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

`comm` compares 2 sorted files and will print 3 columns of output.  First is the lines unique to file1, then lines unique to file2 then lines common to both.  You can supress any columns, so we turn of 1 and 3 in this example with `-13` so we will see only lines unique to the second file.

or you could use `grep`:

```
grep -wvFf file1 file2
```

Here we use `-f` to have grep get its patterns from `file1`.  We then tell it to treat them as fixed strings with `-F` instead of as patterns, match whole words with `-w`, and print only lines with no matches with `-v`

Comment: As I needed to maintain the order so i used the `grep -wvFf file1 file2` but there was no output. Ain't it supposed to print the added line?

Comment: @SujanDulal one thing I noticed from your sample input is one of them has carriage returns and the other doesn't.  If possible you might want to run `dos2unix` on both files so you get rid of those different line endings (otherwise they will be treated as part of the match)

Comment: I actually jumbled the file during input that was the problem. Thank you for the suggestion. I will filter out the carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same. This will tell you all those lines which are present in Input_file2 and not in Input_file1.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of diff and sed.

The raw diff output is:

```
$ diff file1 file2
0a1,2
> /root/new
> /root/new_new
```

Add sed to strip out everything but the lines beginning with ">":

```
$ diff file1 file2 | sed -n -e 's/^> //p'
/root/new
/root/new_new
```

This preserves the order. Note that it also assumes you are only adding lines to the second file.